# How to create faces connecting a curved area

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices

I want to fill this area, and I'm selecting all of the edges and press the key f, it's not as expected. It looks horrible and not filling.

[image: Where i wanna fill]

[image: Not filled]

I tried to see which vertices are connected and it shows that 3 vertices at the other end of the model is somehow connected and I really cant figure out how that happened! In the picture below, you can see the result of choosing one of the vertices down at the bottom -> shift + G -> Amount of connecting edges.

[image: Connected vertices]

The thing is, when I show numbers on the vertices, it doesn't make sense either as the numbers skip at some places which might be the problem of my mesh. But now it's happened 3 times, starting from scratch each time.

[image: Vertice numbers]

What am I missing? and is there a way to save this?

I hope I've made myself clear, but it's kind of a hard problem to describe. Feel free to ask if you need more information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few steps you should do:

1. Select the top vertices (the ones close together) *on both sides.
2. Then when you have those selected search-bar "Bridge edge loop" that will connect it.
3. Now you can select the 'half moon' vertices. press <kbd>F</kbd> this will create a plane.
4. Do this "half moon", make a plan. When you have everything connected you can 'merge' the bigger planes together.
5. Select the faces and press <kbd>F</kbd> this will connect them as I said.

For the oblong like planes you can select the vertices and dissolve them.

Comment: Thank you so much, sir! Fixed it right away!

Answer (score 4):

You can connect the vertices manually.
This will also create proper topology, which is nice.

1. Select two vertices and go *Vertex > New Face from vertices*, <kbd>F</kbd>
2. Repeat, repeat repeat until it's filled
3. Done :).

[image]

Comment: You sir just saved me immense amount of time in the future!

Comment: That's why I'm here :).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I ended up trying the below answer first and it worked. I've taken your advice and will implement in my "toolbox". Thank you!